# Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/ng/areq?p0=PlaneCtrl&p1=not%20a

Tags: angularjs

Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/ng/areq?p0=PlaneCtrl&p1=not%20a            1.#QNAN0unction%2C%20got%20undefined any help for this error in angularjs

```
.state('testing.test', {
            url: '/test-map',
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
            controller: 'PlaneCtrl as plane',
        })
```

;(function() {

```
angular.module('app.controllers')

.controller('PlaneCtrl', function(PlaneSrv) {
    var vm = this;

    PlaneSrv.getSeatmap().success(function(response) {
        if('seatMaps' in response && response.seatMaps.length) {
            vm.seatmap = seatParseHelper(response.seatMaps[0]);
        };
    });

});
```

})();

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.controllers', []);

})();
```

Comment: please provide code.

Comment: you have not registered `PlaneCtrl` controller to your app module

Comment: @PankajParkar controller: 'PlaneCtrl as plane'

Comment: @ahmad You bind `PlaneCtrl as plane` controller with `templateUrl: 'test.html'`, but where you created `PlanCtrl` ?

Comment: @gauravbhavsar in a controller.js
angular.module('app.controllers').controller('PlaneCtrl', function(PlaneSrv)

Comment: Yes, we want to see that code, and code where you have `angular.module` and Html page where you load controller.js ?

Comment: @gauravbhavsar i edited the question

Comment: @ahmad where is `PlaneSrv`? is it defined?